# AG-Grid gridReady not being called on tests with Angular and Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular-testing-library

The `gridReady` method of the Angular AG Grid is not being called in the Jest tests.
Do you know why?

Here you have my test code:

```
import {TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";

describe('AG Grid', () => {
  it('calls grid ready', async()=> {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.api).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.columnApi).toBeDefined();

  });
})
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/cjoecker/ag-grid-testing?file=/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:0-936) you can see a code sandbox for it.
[Here](https://github.com/cjoecker/ag-grid-testing) is a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved using `await fixture.whenStable()` after `fixture.detectChanges()`